# What could be causing my WhatsApp Stickers Pack not to work?

Tags: whatsapp

So I'm busy building my own WhatsApp Stickers Pack for WhatsApp using their tutorial on the WhatsApp Website, but I'm getting this error when trying to add the stickers to WhatsApp: "There's a problem with this sticker pack and it can't be added to WhatsApp".

Here is the link to the WhatsApp guide: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/26000226/?category=5245251

What could be possible problems with it? What could cause this not to work?

[image]

Comment: Did you fixed this issue?? I am facing same problem, can you please guide me for this?

Comment: Hi, @BhoomikaPatel have you solved the issue? can you help me with it?

Comment: @kavindhi yes i solved that. You can refer below answers

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel - I got the same error. I tried following answer but can't solve the issue. can you help me?

Comment: @khushbuvadi can you please check accepted answer. Read all instructions carefully. May be that helps you. In my case, that was issue related to content provider.

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel - I already checked multiple times. I have samsung galaxy device android 11. In some devices it working fine. I checked in motorola  android 11, it's working fine. but not working in my device and one plus. So, I am getting confused now what should I do? I have been searching since last 3 days.

Comment: when I try to add sticker pack it always show this error -  Sticker pack not added. If you'd like to add it make sure you update to the latest version of WhatsApp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

click OK button in this dialog and You will be prompt with another dialog describing an actual reason behind not adding the sticker pack to the WhatsApp.

Basically, from my understanding, it is a naming issue in one of the image file of this sticker packs. Only use small letters, underscore(_) and numbers in the file name. And always start the file name by small letter only.

Make sure you read the [README](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/tree/master/Android) file for Stickers app project.
Follow this file, and You will not get this error anymore.
Happy coding :)

Comment: I have samsung galaxy device android 11. In some devices it working fine. I checked in motorola android 11, it's working fine. but not working in my device and one plus. when I try to add sticker pack it always show this error -  Sticker pack not added. If you'd like to add it make sure you update to the latest version of WhatsApp.  So, I am getting confused now what should I do? I have been searching since last 3 days. can you please help me out with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try adding `aaptOptions {noCompress "webp"}` to build.gradle file under `android` tag and add  `android:readPermission="com.whatsapp.sticker.READ"` to provider manifest then clear cache and data and rebuild

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you need to check your logcat for exceptions that it generates & post it here then only anybody would be able to answer this question properly.

According to my experience there can be following reasons :-

1)Your tray icon is not of specified size which is must.
2)Your images are of varying sizes.
3)Check your id matches with assets folder's name.

here I am providing a link to app where you can get some idea about the implementation :-

WAStickerApps - Mega Sticker Packs
[WAStickerApps - Mega Sticker Packs](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stickers.whatsappstickers)